# while @@FETCH_STATUS=0 is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

See below my trigger that is not working. I have tested this many times and the trigger is working, but not the cursor. I do get a value from `inserted` but it does not  execute 
`WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)`

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TRG_InsertStockMasterDetail] 
ON [dbo].[PrdBallMRRConsumption]
AFTER INSERT AS

Begin


    Declare  @IssueTypeID Int,              @IssueID bigint,                @IssueDate dateTime,                @SupplierID int,            @DepartmentID int,  
             @CompanyID int,                @CreateBy int,              @CreateDate Datetime,           @CreatePC nvarchar(50),     @IsDeleted bit,         
             ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
             @ItemID int ,                  @UOMID int,                 @LotID int,                     @Qty Decimal(18,6),         
             @UnitPrice Decimal(18,6),      @ItemTypeID int,            --@BatchID int,                 @GradeID int,     
             ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                 
             @ReceiveValue Decimal(18,6),   @ReceiveQty Decimal(18, 6), @IssueQty Decimal(18,6),        @IssueValue Decimal(18,6), @StockID bigint,
             @CurrentStock numeric(18, 6),  @CurrentRate numeric(18, 10),   @CurrentStockValue numeric(18, 6),
             @IsStockUpdate bit,            @IsCostingUpdate bit

        ----/// Declare Cursour ///----
        --select BallConsumptionID, YarnCountID, SupplierID, DepartmentID, LotID, LengthM, LengthYds, UnitPrice, Amount, Qty, Unit, Remarks, CompanyID, CreateBy, CreateOn, CreatePc, UpdateBy, UpdateOn, UpdatePc, IsDeleted, DeleteBy, DeleteOn, DeletePc from PrdBallMRRConsumption
    DECLARE Issue_Insert CURSOR FOR 
    Select M.TransactionTypeID,D.BallConsumptionID,M.BalMRRDate,D.SupplierID,D.DepartmentID,D.CompanyID,D.CreateBy,D.CreateOn,D.CreatePc,D.IsDeleted,
    D.YarnCountID ItemID, D.Unit UnitID,D.LotID,D.Qty,D.UnitPrice,(ISNULL(D.Qty,0) * ISNULL(D.UnitPrice,0)) AS ReceiveValue 

    from  Inserted D --PrdBallMRRConsumption
    INNER JOIN PrdBallMRRDetail S ON D.BallConsumptionID=S.BallConsumptionID
    INNER JOIN PrdBallMRRMaster M ON S.BalMRRID=M.BalMRRID

    OPEN Issue_Insert
    FETCH NEXT FROM Issue_Insert 
    INTO @IssueTypeID ,@IssueID ,@IssueDate,@SupplierID ,@DepartmentID , @CompanyID,@CreateBy, @CreateDate,@CreatePC,@IsDeleted,
         -------
         @ItemID , @UOMID,  @LotID, @Qty, @UnitPrice, @ReceiveValue
         ------



    ----/// Loop Cursour ///----
    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)

    BEGIN

    Select @ItemTypeID =  ItemTypeID from CmnItemMaster  where itemid=@ItemID
    select @IsStockUpdate=IsStockUpdate,@IsCostingUpdate=IsCostingUpdate 
    from CmnTransactionTypeERPIntigration 
    Where TransactionTypeID=@IssueTypeID AND CompanyID=@CompanyID


    IF(@IsStockUpdate=1)
        BEGIN
        Select @ReceiveQty =0, @CurrentStock =0, @CurrentRate =0, @CurrentStockValue=0



            IF(ISNULL(@ItemID,'') <> '')
            Begin
            --1 For Random , 2 For FIFO, 3 For LIFO
                   IF((SELECT TOP 1 IntegrationType FROM InvIntegrationType 
                Where  (ISNULL(DepartmentID,0)=0 OR DepartmentID=@DepartmentID) 
                        and CompanyID=@CompanyID)='AVG')


                    BEGIN

                   Update InvStockMaster Set  ReceiveQty = Isnull(ReceiveQty,0) - @Qty, ReceiveValue = Isnull(ReceiveValue,0) - @ReceiveValue,
                                              LastReceiveDate= Case When Isnull(LastReceiveDate,@IssueDate)<=@IssueDate Then @IssueDate Else LastReceiveDate End 
                                                        Where Isnull(CompanyID,0)=Isnull(@CompanyID,0) 
                                                        And   Isnull(DepartmentID,0) = Isnull(@DepartmentID,0) 
                                                        And   Isnull(ItemID,0) = Isnull(@ItemID,0)
                                                        And   Isnull(UOMID,0) = Isnull(@UOMID,0) 
                                                        And   Isnull(SupplierID,0) = Isnull(@SupplierID,0)   
                                                        --AND   ISNULL(BatchID,0)=ISNULL(@BatchID,0) 
                                                        AND   ISNULL(LotID,0)=ISNULL(@LotID,0) 
                                                        --AND   ISNULL(GradeID,0)=ISNULL(@GradeID,0)

                   Select @StockID =  StockID from InvStockMaster   
                                                        Where Isnull(CompanyID,0)=Isnull(@CompanyID,0) 
                                                        And   Isnull(DepartmentID,0) = Isnull(@DepartmentID,0) 
                                                        And   Isnull(ItemID,0) = Isnull(@ItemID,0)
                                                        And   Isnull(UOMID,0) = Isnull(@UOMID,0) 
                                                        And   Isnull(SupplierID,0) = Isnull(@SupplierID,0)   
                                                        --AND   ISNULL(BatchID,0)=ISNULL(@BatchID,0) 
                                                        AND   ISNULL(LotID,0)=ISNULL(@LotID,0) 
                                                        --AND   ISNULL(GradeID,0)=ISNULL(@GradeID,0)

                   INSERT INTO InvStockDetail 
                            (StockID, TransactionID, TransactionTypeID, StockDate, ItemID, ItemTypeID, LotID, SupplierID, DepartmentID, ReceiveQty, ReceiveRate, ReceiveValue, UOMID, CompanyID, CreateBy, CreateOn, CreatePc, IsDeleted)
                    Values  (@StockID, @IssueID, @IssueTypeID, @IssueDate, @ItemID, @ItemTypeID, @LotID, @SupplierID, @DepartmentID, @Qty, @UnitPrice, @ReceiveValue, @UOMID, @CompanyID, @Createby, @CreateDate, @CreatePC, @IsDeleted)



            ----// For Average Cost //----
                --Begin
                IF(@IsCostingUpdate=1)
                    BEGIN
                    Update InvStockMaster Set CurrentRate = CurrentValue/CurrentStock   
                                                Where Isnull(CurrentValue,0) <> 0 And Isnull(CurrentStock,0)<>0 
                                                AND   Isnull(CompanyID,0)=Isnull(@CompanyID,0) 
                                                And   Isnull(DepartmentID,0) = Isnull(@DepartmentID,0) 
                                                And   Isnull(ItemID,0) = Isnull(@ItemID,0)
                                                And   Isnull(UOMID,0) = Isnull(@UOMID,0) 
                                                And   Isnull(SupplierID,0) = Isnull(@SupplierID,0)   
                                                --AND   ISNULL(BatchID,0)=ISNULL(@BatchID,0) 
                                                AND   ISNULL(LotID,0)=ISNULL(@LotID,0) 
                                                --AND   ISNULL(GradeID,0)=ISNULL(@GradeID,0)


                   END                                            
                   END  
            --Comments
            END


        END

        FETCH NEXT FROM Issue_Insert 
        INTO @IssueTypeID ,         @IssueID ,          @IssueDate ,            @SupplierID ,           @DepartmentID , 
             @CompanyID ,           @CreateBy ,         @CreateDate ,       @CreatePC,              @IsDeleted ,            
             -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
             @ItemID  ,             @UOMID ,            @LotID ,            @Qty ,                  @UnitPrice ,    @ReceiveValue 
             --@BatchID, @GradeID ,
End
    CLOSE Issue_Insert
    DEALLOCATE Issue_Insert 

End
```

Comment: Does this bit return any rows: `select * from  Inserted D 
    INNER JOIN PrdBallMRRDetail S ON D.BallConsumptionID=S.BallConsumptionID
    INNER JOIN PrdBallMRRMaster M ON S.BalMRRID=M.BalMRRID`

Comment: yes it return data. i have also create a trigger like this before in another table. that is working fine. but it does not worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the structure is correct, only thing I can think of is data related, there is no records to fetch next from, make sure the query below returns more than one row

```
 Select M.TransactionTypeID,D.BallConsumptionID,M.BalMRRDate,D.SupplierID,D.DepartmentID,D.CompanyID,D.CreateBy,D.CreateOn,D.CreatePc,D.IsDeleted,
D.YarnCountID ItemID, D.Unit UnitID,D.LotID,D.Qty,D.UnitPrice,(ISNULL(D.Qty,0) * ISNULL(D.UnitPrice,0)) AS ReceiveValue 

from  Inserted D --PrdBallMRRConsumption
INNER JOIN PrdBallMRRDetail S ON D.BallConsumptionID=S.BallConsumptionID
INNER JOIN PrdBallMRRMaster M ON S.BalMRRID=M.BalMRRID
```

I also looked at my code now and I don't put brackets on my while statement

```
------------------------------  
--  CURSOR FOR MULTISITES   --
------------------------------
-- create the dynamic sql to exec data from the appropriate sites   
declare @sql_table table (sql_cmd nvarchar(max), site_id int)  
declare @sql nvarchar(max), @sql_siteid int  

insert @sql_table (sql_cmd, site_id)  
select   
    'exec '+s.name+'.dbo.[proc_To_run] @MarketingCampaignID,@siteid,@start_date,@end_date'
    ,a.site_id  
from aux_site a  
inner join cnt_this_company_sites cs on cs.siteid = a.site_id
inner join sys.databases s on dbo.sitename(a.site_name) = s.name  
where is_active = 1  


DECLARE __curs_MultiSite CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR   
SELECT sql_cmd, site_id  from @sql_table  

open __curs_MultiSite  

fetch next from __curs_MultiSite into @sql, @sql_siteid  

while @@fetch_status = 0  
begin       
    insert into #ME_Data       
    EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL            --  This method of exec-ing is supposedly SQL Injection safe  
    @sql              --  The sql to exec  
    ,N'@MarketingCampaignID INT, @SiteId INT, @start_date DATETIME, @end_date DATETIME'  --  Define the params that occur within @sql_current   
    ,@MarketingCampaignID
    ,@sql_siteid
    ,@start_date
    ,@end_date                  

    --reseed
    fetch next from __curs_MultiSite into @sql, @sql_siteid   
end    
close __curs_MultiSite   
deallocate __curs_MultiSite     
--END CURSOR __curs_MultiSite
```

Comment: yes. now i find the problem.. when i tried to get data it return NULL. thanks fro helping me